# How can I switch between 12 hour and 24 hour format in command line?

Tags: command-line, time, gsettings

I am in a learning phase. I could not find the command to change my time format from 12 hour to 24 hour. Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you!!

Comment: Do you want to get the time or set the time from terminal?

Comment: Hi Abhishek. Could you give some feedback on the answers? Was it what you were looking for? please mention.

Answer (score 14):

Time settings, as as shown in the panel, are set with `gsettings`. You can set 12/24 hrs by the commands:

12-hour:

[image]

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 12-hour
```

24-hour:

[image]

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.datetime time-format 24-hour
```

options are:

```
locale-default
12-hour
24-hour
custom
```

#### The same trick on Mate

...requires a different command:

12-hour:

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/format "'12-hour'"
```

and, as one would expect, 24-hour:

```
dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/format "'24-hour'"
```

*N.B.* tested on Mate 16.04 by @Zana (thanks!)

Comment: I like this answer a lot (I upvoted it also) but in MATE I get 'no such schema' :( and in fact `gsettings list-recursively | grep time-format` returns nothing at all. I wonder how I can do it...

Comment: @Zanna, what version of Mate do you run? I found two settings that *should* work if settings made sense, but they don't change a thing on my VM: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format 12h` and `dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/format "'12-hour'"`. (Mate 15.10)

Comment: First one does nothing for me either (even on reboot), but `dconf write /org/mate/panel/objects/clock/prefs/format "'12-hour"' ` works instantly (I undid it - I hate 12 hr clock haha)

Comment: @Zanna Greatgreat! thanks for testing, will add it to the answer :)

Comment: ^_^ my pleasure. Now trying the same in Xubuntu... `dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/clock-format "'12-hour'"` should do it, but doesn't >_< I'll come back if I fix it

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I tried `"'12-hour"'` and was unable to run till I did `"'12-hour'"` although my time still the same. Is that a typo in the answer?

Comment: Hi @George I am on mobile currently, but I am pretty sure you are right, I will edit it in. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I used the code in Ubuntu Mate 18.04 and it worked fine. But when I restart the PC, it is back to 24Hour format again.

Answer (score 11):

It is not clear to me what exactly do you want. If you want just display the hour in your terminal window, you can try:

```
date +%R
date +%r
date +%H
date +%I
date +%H:%M
date +%I:%M
```

These are different time formats used to customize your time display. `%R` uses time with 24 hour and `%r` uses 12 hour format to display the whole time. If you want just hour with no minutes, etc. you can use `%H` (24 hour) or `%I` (12 hour). You can also combine them with minutes like that `%H:%M`, `%I:%M`. There are many other options. Take a look with `man date`.

Then if you want to change the system global date display go to `Settings -> Region & Language`.

There is also environment setting `LC_TIME` specifiying how time & date are displayed. In my case I can set it up in `/etc/environment` file like this:

```
LC_TIME="sl_SI.UTF-8"
```

You can also take a look at `/etc/localtime`. Try:

```
ls -l /etc/localtime
```

This file is linked to some file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`. Make a link like this:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Ljubljana /etc/localtime
```

and your local settings will be set to European Ljubljana, for instance. Fell free to use any other file from `/usr/share/zoneinfo/`. However, I believe this last settings is only setting for the timezone and not how the date & time are displayed.

Comment: I've linked /etc/localtime to the appropriate timezone, but I still get a 12-hour format (but the right timezone offset from GMT).  I have no LC* or other variables set.  (I get the correct output with `LC_TIME=..... date`, but I would like to have 24-hour time as the default.

Comment: Take a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/918973/how-to-set-lc-time-variable-to-en-dk-while-keeping-en-us-the-system-default-for, how to setup LC_TIME.

Comment: Thanks.  It might be that the locale needs to be "enabled".  However, I discovered that `LANG` was set to `en_US.UTF-8` in my shell, 'unset'ing this environment variable changed the output of `date` to 24h format.  (I haven't figured out how it got set in the first place, though.)

Comment: My brain shorts out when I try to read `Ljubljana`

Comment: @SamSirry :-) Read or pronounce? Try this https://ebralec.si/branje/?jezik=en. Paste `Ljubljana` in there and listen.

Answer (score 5):

For new users, if you are using gnome on ubuntu version >18.04

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format 12h
```

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-format 24h
```

Answer (score 3):

The locale settings can affect the time display format for the `date` command. E.g. With `en_US` it is 12-hour:

```
% LANG='en_US.UTF-8'; date
Tue 14 Jul 2020 09:13:29 PM BST
```

And 24-hour for `en_GB`:

```
% LANG='en_GB.UTF-8'; date
Tue 14 Jul 2020 21:13:29 PM BST
```

This can be changed for the system by running the following command (provided you have the appropriate language files installed):

```
sudo update-locale LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8 LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

Comment: `*** update-locale: Error: invalid locale settings:  LANGUAGE=en_GB.UTF-8 LANG=en_GB.UTF-8` can be fixed with `sudo locale-gen "en_GB.UTF-8"`

Comment: That error message usually means that the requested locale files are not installed - they can be installed: `sudo apt install language-pack-XX`