# How to set LC_TIME variable to en_DK while keeping en_US the system default for other variables?

Tags: locale

I have the system default set to `en_US.UTF-8`. But (among other nonsensical things) this makes Sunday (a weekend day) the first day of the week in calendars.

I want to use the `LC_TIME` variable from `en_DK.UTF-8` while keeping the `en_US.UTF-8` variables for everything else.

I have generated both `en_US.UTF-8` and `en_DK.UTF-8` and I used to be able to simply edit `/etc/default/locale` by adding the line `LC_TIME="en_DK.UTF-8"`.

But this is no longer working and I have no idea why. So how can I get this working again?

Before people start telling me to hack on the `en_US.UTF-8` text file (at `/usr/share/i18n/locales`), this doesn't work either because updates periodically reset this. I want to know what the "proper" way of configuring for this is.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I would do:

1. check which locales are enabled:

   ```
   grep -v '^#' /etc/locale.gen
   ```

   You should at least get (Or something similar):

   ```
   en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
   ```
2. Enable it if it's not and disable unnecessary locales by commenting those lines.
3. generate locales:

   ```
   sudo locale-gen
   ```
4. set default locales:

   ```
   sudo localectl set-locale LANG=en_US.utf8 LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
   ```
5. check All important files like: `.profile`, `.bashrc` and other startup files to make sure nothing is overwriting our configurations.

it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Open `~/.profile` for editing and add this line:

```
export LC_TIME=en_DK.UTF-8
```

On Ubuntu GNOME you may also need to run this command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.system.locale region
```

Comment: I tried this before posting here. Unfortunately it didn't work. The problem appears to be GNOME DE overriding everything. GNOME is doing everything it can to prevent me from changing date format.

Comment: @user308393: Please see the edited answer. I came to think of [bug #1662031](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1662031), but editing `~/.profile` proved to be a workaround of that bug too.